# Display Data from Two Tables and Eliminate Duplicates

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Good Afternoon. Before I ask my Question I want to show you my Database and Tables.

I have two Tables in MySQL

Table 1: purchorder

[image]

Table 2: receiving

[image]

as what you see on the 1st table the RINumbeR in Table `pucrhorder` has been updated in table `receiving`. Now I`m targeting to do something like this.

[image]

Before I post this Question I tried to code it but my Output is this:

[image]

and the code for that is:

```
 Private Sub POHistory_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim con1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=admin1950;database=inventory")
        Dim sql1 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("select purchorder.PONo,purchorder.ItemCode,purchorder.Description,purchorder.OrderQty,receiving.RINo,receiving.ItemCode,receiving.Description,receiving.ReceivedQty from purchorder,receiving where Purchorder.PONo = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' = receiving.RINo = '" & TextBox2.Text & "' GROUP BY Purchorder.ItemCode;", con1)
        Dim ds1 As DataSet = New DataSet
        Dim adapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
        con1.Open()
        adapter1.SelectCommand = sql1
        adapter1.Fill(ds1, "MyTable")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
        con1.Close()
    End Sub
```

What to do? Do I need to use Joins in MYSQL? Datagridview paint? Any Help is appreciated. All I want is to Display the Data like on the Image Above (With the Yellow Header)

TYSM

Comment: Left outer join would probably be good.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the output I want? Like on the image above? How? What code can be use? Can u give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you use JOIN and GROUP BY you will have the result of both tables and no duplicate on the column you have grouped

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the output I want? Like on the image above? How? What code can be use? Can u give me an example?

Comment: Yes it's possible to have blank spaces and sub groups but I didn't have a query to show you